# Is it normal that my bluetooth gamepad only reach 5m/15ft?

Tags: hardware

I do a lot of gaming from my couch which is placed ~5m/15ft from my computer. I use a Logitech F710 game pad and/or keyboard/mouse with bluetooth connection to the computer. What's super annoying is that is JUST inside the range of what the bluetooth manages. If I sit in the oppsite end of the couch, the connection is lost. This goes both for the F710 and the keyboard (also Logitech).

- Is this an inherent problem with bluetooth?
- Would it help if I only had one bluetooth device instead of 3? Do they interfer with each other?
- Is there any configuration/tuning I can do to improve the range?

The F710 is kindof worthless if I can't sit in my couch while gaming. Any tips to improve my gaming experience appreciated.

Comment: I believe this question would be better suited for [su].

Comment: you're lucky it even reaches that far. bluetooth is meant for super close range. use IR if you want to go long.

Comment: So... are there any IR gamepads for PC out there?

Comment: Are the keyboard and mouse also Logitech?  They can be mapped (using the driver software) to all use the same Logitech unified receiver that you use for your F710.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to pass a, possibly long, [usb extension cable](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=j7QuVZTjN8uC8QeatoC4Dw&gws_rd=ssl#q=usb+extension+cable) so the dongle for your logitech hardware would be closer to the couch.

Comment: I like this simple yet effective suggestion. It answers my third bullet point in a creative way so I don't see why anyone would downvote it. Come with a better suggestion if you have one!

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth Rx/Tx chips are typically manufactured to serve in maximum 10 meter range till version 3.0, but this is for technically optimal space, meaning absolute no interference, shielding, blockage. A safe range to use Bluetooth is between 3-7 meter from the base (in 3 meters you may want to stay on cable, and Bluetooth is counterproductive), so being able to use bluetooth device only in 5 meter is not good rate, but reasonable. You can call this **"inherent issue"**, however I doubt it would be any time workarounded or solved. The issue is by design till 3.0. Bluetooth 4.0+ can cover larger area, but I think it is out of scope for gaming devices, and I have no practical experience with them.

**Bluetooth devices interfere.** Not only with each other, but possibly with your WiFi channel also, as both technology uses 2.4GHz for communication. If it is possible for Logitech F710 to set bluetooth channel by it's desktop software, make sure it is different from your set WiFi channel. It is best to keep only 1 BT device. Sadly.

For best effort I agree with Jonathan Drapeau to get **USB extension cable.** You can still try to check what other interferences or can you eliminate, or if adapters are not having straight-line clear view on each other, make sure no shielding would block the signal.